# FQL to know if a user like a page

Tags: facebook, facebook-fql

I need to know for my development if the user liked the page.
In my first try, it worked very well, but since I moved the development on another page, it doesn't work anymore.

I checked on the graph.facebook.com/ to get the ID of the new page (In my case https://graph.facebook.com/CodeRougeAuto for the new one and graph.facebook.com/765427430147858 for the old one, and here for my testing user http://graph.facebook.com/developpement.prod).

Both pages are liked by my user account, but when I test the FQL in Graph explorer, only the old page returns the UID (the query is SELECT uid FROM page_fan WHERE uid=xxxxxxxxxxxxxx AND page_id=xxxxxxxxxxxxxx)

I use this javascript to know if an user like the page :

```
FB.api({method: 'fql.query', query: 'SELECT uid FROM page_fan WHERE uid=' + FBUser.id + ' AND page_id=260226614127613', access_token: FBAccessToken}, function(result) { });
```

Could you explain me why the FQL don't return the uid ?
Thank you.

Comment: Could you put some code up? Otherwise we'd just be guessing what the issue is.

Comment: For testing, I use the tool from Facebook : https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer No code is needed for my problem. I put the javascript code used.

Comment: Now when I try this FQL query : SELECT uid FROM page_fan WHERE uid=100007829408579 AND page_id=260226614127613 (uid = testing user and page_id the new page) I get this response : (#606) The global ID 100007829408579 is not allowed. Please use the application specific ID instead....